# What is a fork database?

Tags: nodeos, block-producer, blocks, irreversible-state

There is a mention of a fork database in the docs for the [bnet_plugin](https://developers.eos.io/eosio-nodeos/docs/bnet_plugin). Could you please tell me what the fork database is and how is it related to the state of the nodeos node?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [the code](https://github.com/EOSIO/eos/blob/13952d4505d56442a769528bdf6094b52768b2cd/libraries/chain/include/eosio/chain/fork_database.hpp#L13-L22):

```
   /**
    * @class fork_database
    * @brief manages light-weight state for all potential unconfirmed forks
    *
    * As new blocks are received, they are pushed into the fork database. The fork
    * database tracks the longest chain and the last irreversible block number. All
    * blocks older than the last irreversible block are freed after emitting the
    * irreversible signal.
    */
```

and from [the whitepaper](https://github.com/EOSIO/Documentation/blob/master/TechnicalWhitePaper.md#consensus-algorithm-bft-dpos):

> Under normal conditions a DPOS blockchain does not experience any
>   forks because, rather than compete, the block producers cooperate to
>   produce blocks. In the event there is a fork, consensus will
>   automatically switch to the longest chain. This method works because
>   the rate at which blocks are added to a blockchain fork is directly
>   correlated to the percentage of block producers that share the same
>   consensus. In other words, a blockchain fork with more producers on it
>   will grow in length faster than one with fewer producers, because the
>   fork with more producers will experience fewer missed blocks.
>
> Furthermore, no block producer should be producing blocks on two forks
>   at the same time. A block producer caught doing this will likely be
>   voted out. Cryptographic evidence of such double-production may also
>   be used to automatically remove abusers.

Thus, my understanding is that the "fork database" represents the chain of blocks that a producer keeps track of that are not yet irreversible but are considered the longest chain according to the view of that BP.

Answer (score 2):

Fork database is all the valid reversible blocks your node received, once the longest branch has the irreversible block, the branches from the irreversible block will be removed.